# Animating particle system

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes

I'm trying to animate a turret firing sets of two laser bolts, but I want to be able to stop and start the process. I read an answer saying to set a keyframe for the particle system, but I don't know how to do that.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this the one you are referring to? [How to turn particle emission on/off?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-to-turn-particle-emission-on-off). I'm considering close voting on your question as being a duplicate of that one. I haven't quite decided yet, but others may not be be hesitant. If you try to clarify exactly what you do not understand, it will be easier to help.

Comment: I suppose my question is a further clarification of that one, I looked to it to determine what to do but I don't know how to set keyframes for the particle effect properties, that's the heart of my question

Comment: Setting a keyframe for any property that can be keyframed, is as simple as hovering the mouse over it and pressing `I` or right clicking it and selecting `Insert Keyframe`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, I'll try to ask more clear and concise questions in the future

Comment: You're welcome. And since this solved your problem, I will cast that close vote, because all you needed was a clarification of the answer given there.