# How to repeat an emitter 'burst'

Tags: particles, fcurves

I have a plane acting as a simple emitter. It emits 10 particles from frame 1 to 4. And again from frame 11-14. And again from 21-24. Then there's a pause for 40 frames, and the entire sequence repeats, including the pause.

I need to find an automated way to cycle this emitter sequence. Ideally, the sequence could be repeated indefinitely using an F-Curve Cycles modifier.

The question below addresses a similar problem, but I'm looking for a way to use automation:
[How to turn particle emission on/off?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-to-turn-particle-emission-on-off)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah in the link you provided there was a good answer.

I made a clear answer out of it: **[Just animate the Velocity of the particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118152/8282)**.

[image]

You can automate the curve with F-Curve Cycles modifier (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

If it annoys you that the 0-velocity particles keep popping up, you can model a structure around the emitter:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manu :) I asked my question two hours before you posted your answer in the linked question. If I'd known this question from May, 2013 was going to get a good answer two hours after I asked, I would've waited :)